# How to fix scroll bar and screen cut in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clone WhatsApp web page login, I have created a part of HTML and CSS, but has there is an error in my code, the scroll bar doesn't work and the content of the page doesn't appear, like a video, the video appear just a part, to exemplify better, below is the print of the page and my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #dddbd1;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Lucida Grande, Arial, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}

header.main-header {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00bfa5;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 0; */
}

header.main-header .content {
  display: flex;
}

header.main-header .content section {
  margin: 30px 45px 30px 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header.main-header .content img {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header.main-header .content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19), 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  position: relative;
}

div.landing-main {
  display: flex;
}

div.landing-main .steps {
  padding: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

div.landing-main .steps h2 {
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.landing-main .steps ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.landing-main .steps ol li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div.landing-main .scanner {
  margin-top: auto;
}

div.menu .video {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<header class="main-header">
  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <img src="/assets/icons8-whatsapp.svg" alt="Logo">
      <p>WHATSAPP WEB</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="menu">

  <div class="landing-main">

    <div class="steps">
      <h2>To Use Whatsapp on your computer:</h2>
      <ol>
        <li><span>1. Open Whatsapp on your phone</span></li>
        <li><span>2. Tap Menu <img src="/assets/more.svg" alt=""> or Settings <img src="/assets/icons8-settings.svg" alt=""> and select Whatsapp Web</span></li>
        <li><span>3. Point your phone to this screen to capture the code</span></li>
      </ol>
    </div>


    <div class="scanner">
      <img src="/assets/download.png" alt="Scanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <video src="/assets/whatsapp-webclient-login_a0f99e8cbba9eaa747ec23ffb30d63fe.html"></video>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden;` from `*`

Comment: yes, is this, but now stayed with the part white above

Comment: work around it (place on the element needed), you cant simply place overflow: hidden; on every element

Comment: I withdrew the position relative of the main-header, and it's work, but now my div.menu don't be on the header

Comment: the image doesn't match your code (snippet) or is the screen actually whats app (dont know never used it), to pull up the main section tweak margin-top: 100px; it should probably be negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change overflow:hidden to auto

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  background: #dddbd1;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Lucida Grande, Arial, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}

header.main-header {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00bfa5;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 0; */
}

header.main-header .content {
  display: flex;
}

header.main-header .content section {
  margin: 30px 45px 30px 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header.main-header .content img {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header.main-header .content p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19), 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  position: relative;
}

div.landing-main {
  display: flex;
}

div.landing-main .steps {
  padding: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

div.landing-main .steps h2 {
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.landing-main .steps ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.landing-main .steps ol li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div.landing-main .scanner {
  margin-top: auto;
}

div.menu .video {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<header class="main-header">
  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <img src="/assets/icons8-whatsapp.svg" alt="Logo">
      <p>WHATSAPP WEB</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="menu">

  <div class="landing-main">

    <div class="steps">
      <h2>To Use Whatsapp on your computer:</h2>
      <ol>
        <li><span>1. Open Whatsapp on your phone</span></li>
        <li><span>2. Tap Menu <img src="/assets/more.svg" alt=""> or Settings <img src="/assets/icons8-settings.svg" alt=""> and select Whatsapp Web</span></li>
        <li><span>3. Point your phone to this screen to capture the code</span></li>
      </ol>
    </div>


    <div class="scanner">
      <img src="/assets/download.png" alt="Scanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <video src="/assets/whatsapp-webclient-login_a0f99e8cbba9eaa747ec23ffb30d63fe.html"></video>
  </div>

</div>
```